# Could not instantiate mail function in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to send an **email notification** to user after **checkout is done and order placed**. I've gone through the WooCommerce email settings and set them all accordingly. But for a reason that I don't know of email couldn't be sent. **I understand this is not a code related question.**

...And this is the warning I get in the log plugin to check whether emails have been sent: "  **Could not instantiate mail function** ".

[image]

Comment: You should provide the related code used for it as without that we don't know what you are using to get that error.

Comment: Actually I haven't code myself. As far as I know WooCommerce itself have those features in WooCommerce>Settings>Email. Isn't these configurations enough or I should code it myself to send an email after order is placed?

Comment: No sorry this is custom code and there is many classes related to emails and it depend on how this has been made. So you need to provide what has been used to get that. If it's a third party plugin, you should contact authors support threads.

Comment: May be you should try sending dummy mail to you from contact form. Check whether you get that or not. If you get that mail it means your mail function works, and if any error occurs that means there is some PHP mail(); function error. Then you should try using SMTP plugin to send and receive emails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens due to your site haven't been configured with email service provider like Google/SendGrid or SMTP. In my case, I used SMTP with the help of WP Mail SMTP plugin, and it works for me. Example configuration can be found below:
[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: I am going to try this, what I couldn't understand is suddenly my mail has stopped working once I move my test setup from sub domain to main domain, what can explain this behaviour?